# What icon does the OS use for badging notifications in the notification center?

Tags: ios

The icons used in the notification center are not the same as the app icons displayed on the desktop - for example set an alert in the calendar, when it is displayed the calendar icon in the notification center is different from the calendar application icon.

Therefore which icon does the notification center use for its notifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses the application icon. Just ignore the calendar, it's a bit special (it's the only non-static icon in Springboard).